# I want to set names in all shapes in PowerPoint using vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I hope this is a super simple question but for some reason i cant figure it out.
I have many shapes in powerpoint slide like Rectangle 1,Rectangle 2,Rectangle 3,
Rectangle 4,Rectangle 5,Rectangle 6 so on & Pentagon 1,Pentagon 2,Pentagon 3,
Pentagon 4,Pentagon 5,Pentagon 6 ...... with unique names & many icons(Graphics).
I want to change all names in shapes & change icons also.

I tried this

```
Sub shapeText()

Application.Presentations(1).Slides(1).Shapes(Rectangle 1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "DOG"
Application.Presentations(1).Slides(1).Shapes(Rectangle 2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "CAT"
Application.Presentations(1).Slides(1).Shapes(Pentagon 1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "WATER"
Application.Presentations(1).Slides(1).Shapes(Pentagon 2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "FIRE"


End Sub
```

Its a lengthy process(have to do for 90 lines).I think it may be done easily with array.
It will be huge help if all data ("DOG","CAT","WATER","FIRE",........)extract from excel
sheet & change will be in powerpoint slide.

Comment: How do you know which shape should have which name??

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed, but shape names on a slide do not have predictable names unless you hand-edit them. The number at the end of the name is incremented for every shape added to the slide, so you'll never have a default slide that will have both Rectangle 1 and Pentagon 1. Also, your requirement to change icons is not clear. Which icons? Or do you mean you want to change the shape type?

Comment: As I tried i changed the text of shape rectangular 1 to "DOG" using above line of code.but shape numbers are not in just 1,2,3.....in order(I used in question for better understanding) it's random number ie rectangle 5,rectangle 11,.......Etc.Icon (ie Bluetooth, wifi,....) is placed inside a rectangular shape.So i want to change wifi icon to aeroplane icon using url.

Comment: @SAHU You'll need to name your shapes in the beginning and only then you would be able to change `.TextFrame` via a `list`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to name all shapes.
If you want to use names from array for instance `list =  array("dog", "square" ... etc)`  , then simple use `shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = list(counter)`

```
Sub nameAllShapes()

    Dim slide As slide
    Dim shape As shape
    Dim counter As Integer

    counter = 1
    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shape In slide.Shapes
            shape.Name = "shapetype:" & shape.Type & "_no:" & counter
            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = shape.Name
            counter = counter + 1
        Next shape
    Next slide
End Sub
```

Comment: all shapes are not in increasing order it's random like rectangle 5,rectangle 24,rectangle 8.....Etc.I used in question in increasing order for easy understanding.sorry for that.I want to change the text "MOUSE"(for example) of shape rectangular 5 to text "DOG"(for example).

Comment: The shape order is not based on their visual position on the slide but rather the order the shapes were created. Which is why your approach to naming shapes by iterating shapes will not necessarily work, unless you order the collection in a meaningful way.